# What’s the consensus on signaling the open/close state for an accordion menu?

Tags: accordion

Should the caret point down when the menu is down, or point up? See example.

[image]

Comment: Binary indicators for action states are always difficult - are you showing the current state or what *will* happen when you click? Definitely a duplicate as the same thinking applies.

Answer (score 0):

I've definitely seen both, for a recent project I used:

- > for collapsed
- v for expanded

I think it does a better job at quickly explaining what the UI will do.

Comment: That's what you've used. But what is the industry standard?